# thisarg confusion in call method in Javascript

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6

```js
function Product(name, price) {
  this.name = name;
  this.price = price;
}

function Food(name, price) {
  Product.call(this, name, price);
  console.log(this);
  this.category = 'food';
}
console.log(new Food('cheese', 5).name);
```

In `Product.call(this, name, price)`, what is the use of `this` value and where it is pointing, or what value does it have when we are calling `Product`?

Comment: This is literally the sample code from the documentation on MDN.  https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/call.  What part of the documentation wasn't clear?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I see that you're referring to the example on:
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/call

Scrolling down to: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/call#Using_call_to_chain_constructors_for_an_object seems to give the best description of what you are looking at.